# What causes the Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined in this form validator class?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I am working on a form validator class in JavaScript:

```js
class FormValidator {
  constructor() {
    this.formToValidate = document.querySelector("form");
    this.submitButton = this.formToValidate.querySelector("input[type=submit]");
  }

  validateForm() {
    console.log('test');
  }

  submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.validateForm();
  }

  init(e) {
    this.formToValidate.addEventListener('submit', this.submitForm(e));
  }
}

const formValidator = new FormValidator();
formValidator.init();
```

```html
<form action="/" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" value="" required />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" value="" required />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone Number" value="" required />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mb-0">
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Send Message" />
  </div>
</form>
```

I get a  `Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined` error whose cause I have not been able to find.

Comment: `('submit', this.submitForm(e))` is not how you add an event listener when `this.submitForm` doesn't return a function.

Comment: If you run the snippet you get the reason. You're calling `init` but not supplying `e`. Because there is no `e` to be supplied. So, when you *immediately call* call `this.submitForm(e)` you're passing `e` as `undefined. 1. Remove `e` from `init`. 2. Don't immediately call `this.submitForm` but use `(e) => this.submitForm(e)` as a callback

Comment: Also You did not pass `e` in `formValidator.init()`;
,

Comment: @Nur what do you think should be passed there to make the code work?

Comment: @VLAZ, The implementor know that, I don't...

Comment: @Nur `e` is forwarded to `this.submitForm(e)` and then consumed as if it's DOM event. There is no event to be passed *at the time of calling `.init()`*. Moreover, no event *should* be passed because `this.submitForm()` should not even be called immediately but when an event occurs. Therefore, there is nothing that *can* be passed that makes any sense. Unless you pass in a synthetic object that just satisfies the consumer `{ preventDefault() {} }`. However that will merely stop the explicit error and makes the code silently fail to do anything useful. So, there is nothing to pass in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change

```js
init(e) {
    this.formToValidate.addEventListener('submit', this.submitForm(e));
}
```

to

```js
init(e) {
    this.formToValidate.addEventListener('submit', () => this.submitForm(e));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You have an argument e in init function which is undefined. Just use:

```
init() {
        this.formToValidate.addEventListener('submit', this.submitForm);
      }
```